# Using HXT to modify XML

Tags: haskell, hxt

I'm trying to modify an XML file of the form:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://s3.xyz.amazonaws.com/xyz/xyz.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://s3.xyz.amazonaws.com/xyz/xyz.57x57.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I want to modify the contents of the node `<string>https://s3.xyz.amazonaws.com/xyz/xyz.ipa</string>`

I can find the related sibling node with the following

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

main = do
  plistString <- readFile "manifest.plist"
  let plistDoc = readString [withValidate no, withSubstDTDEntities no] plistString
  node <- runX  $ plistDoc >>> deep (hasText ( == "software-package")) 
  print node
```

but I don't seem to be able to select the associated sibling nodes (tried `followingSiblingAxis` and `moveUp >>> getChildren`) which would then allow me to manipulate the required node. Is it a problem to do with the difference between `NavigatableTree` and `NTree`; the node I'm `show`s as `NTree (XText "software-package") []]`

It would really help me if any answers assume a very limited exposure to arrows.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to move up *twice*, since with `hasText`, you obtain the *text element*, not the `<string>` tag. As you can see with the `XText`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for hint which sounds right, however I'm struggling to compose `moveUp` with the above. It seems `withNav` might need to be in the mix but I'm fighting type errors without success when I'm trying to compose the whole expression. Any more hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem in a different way. It doesn't feel as robust (matching a substring for `xyz.ipa`), but it unblocked me while I await inspiration:

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Data.Char (toUpper)

uppercase = map toUpper

main = do
  plistString <- readFile "manifest.plist"
  let plistDoc = readString [withValidate no, withSubstDTDEntities no] plistString
  node <- runX . xshow $ plistDoc >>> processTopDown (ifA (hasText ( isInfixOf "xyz.ipa")) (changeText uppercase) (this))
  print node
```